# ggplot2: plotting bars when using stat_summary()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

Here is my current script and the output:

```
ggplot(data.and.factors.prov,aes(x=assumptions,y=FP,
                       colour=factor(Design.Complexity))) +
       stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal,position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
       geom_blank() + scale_colour_manual(values=1:7,name='Design Complexity') + 
       coord_flip()
```

[image]

**How can I have (horizontal) bars (starting at FP=0 and ending at the point position) instead of points ?** (I don't want to lose the error bars)

I'd like to give you my data.and.factors.prov data.table but it is too big to be posted ! If you need a reproducible example, please let me know how I can give you my data set ?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the `stat_summary()` default geom is `"pointrange"`. To get the bars and errorbars one solution is to use two `stat_summary()` calls - one to make errorbars and second to calculate just mean values and plot bars. You will need also to adjust `width=` inside the `position_dodge(`) and `fill=` to the same factor as for `colour=` to change filling of bars.

Here is an example with `mtcars` data.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(cyl),y=mpg,colour=factor(gear),fill=factor(gear))) +  
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal,position=position_dodge(0.95),geom="errorbar") + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,position=position_dodge(width=0.95),geom="bar")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: what does `position=position_dodge(0.95)` do?

Comment: position=position_dodge(x) applies a dodge of x to each point. This moves the points somewhat and separates them.